# how to view database data in vertical way

Tags: php, while-loop

Here is my code to view data from db. some of the column must be get from other table so it will have different query. the problem is, why the second and third *'while loop'* show the result in horizontal way and not vertical.

```
//FIRST WHILE
$result = $waran->getall();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

            echo "<tr>"; 
            echo "   <td style='text-align:center'>".$bil."</td>"; 
            if($_SESSION['mPosition'] == "FULL ACCESS"){
            echo "   <td><a href='javascript:showDialog(\"view_Waran\");showWaran(\"".$row['id']."\")' class='no_decoration'>".$row["name_position"]."</a></td>"; 
            }else{
            echo "   <td>".$row['name_position']."</td>";
            }
            echo "   <td style='text-align:center'>".$row['grade_position']."</td>";
            echo "   <td style='text-align:center'>".$row['code_skim']."</td>";
            //SECOND WHILE
            $resultWaranFix = $waran->getListWaranFix();
            while ($rowWaranFix = mysql_fetch_array($resultWaranFix )) {
                echo "<td>".$rowWaranFix ['total_waran_fix']."</td>"; 
            }

            //THIRD WHILE
            $resultFullfilmentFix = $waran->countFullfilmentFix ();
            while ($rowFullfilmentFix = mysql_fetch_array($resultFullfilmentFix )) {
                echo "<td>".$rowFullfilmentFix ['fullfilment_fix']."</td>"; 
            }

            echo "</tr>";
            $bil=$bil+1;
        }
```

Comment: In the loops you add <td>, which is table cells in a row. All cells in a row is displayed horizontal (by default). You could change this to become tables inside tables or switch to a multi level list to display it more easily.

Comment: when im not add <td> there, the results will be displayed out of table

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
$result = $waran->getall();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

  echo "<tr>";
  echo "   <td style='text-align:center'>".$bil."</td>";
  if($_SESSION['mPosition'] == "FULL ACCESS"){
    echo "   <td><a href='javascript:showDialog(\"view_Waran\");showWaran(\"".$row['id']."\")' class='no_decoration'>".$row["name_position"]."</a></td>";
  }else{
    echo "   <td>".$row['name_position']."</td>";
  }
  echo "   <td style='text-align:center'>".$row['grade_position']."</td>";
  echo "   <td style='text-align:center'>".$row['code_skim']."</td>";

  // You could end the row here for example.
  echo "</tr><tr>";

  // Instead of just adding cells you can put a table inside the cell and display all those items as rows in the sub table.
  echo "<td><table>";

  $resultWaranFix = $waran->getListWaranFix();
  while ($rowWaranFix = mysql_fetch_array($resultWaranFix )) {
    echo "<tr><td>".$rowWaranFix ['total_waran_fix']."</td></tr>";
  }
  echo "</table></td>";

  echo "</tr><tr>";

  // Same for this loop.
  echo "<td><table>";

  $resultFullfilmentFix = $waran->countFullfilmentFix ();
  while ($rowFullfilmentFix = mysql_fetch_array($resultFullfilmentFix )) {
    echo "<tr><td>".$rowFullfilmentFix ['fullfilment_fix']."</td></tr>";
  }

  echo "</table></td>";

  echo "</tr>";
  $bil=$bil+1;
}
```

I have changed it so the loops inside are displayed inside sub tables.

Comment: if i'm implement it like this, all the data will be squeezed in the same row. because it will make sure to do while loop until all data displayed.how to modified it to make sure only one data appeared per row. @andeersg

Comment: I updated the code. Now the stuff before the second loop is a row, the second loop is a row and the third loop is a row.